# Output Robotmodel Position in rviz

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just started learning ros. I followed the turtlebot tutorial to do robot navigation. But I need to store the trace of robot position to an individual file instead of displaying on rviz. The position is displayed in rviz->robotmodel->links->base_link.
I thought I could find this data in topic list but I did not. What can I do to access those position data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237958/output-robotmodel-position-in-rviz/) by [wwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/27271/wwei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably the display you are using in RViz is [TF](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/TF). So have a look at [Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials). Particularly, you can use [tf::TransformListener](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29) to get a coordinate frame transformation between '/world' and '/base_link' frames to acquire robot's pose in global frame.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2016-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0